# SQL CASE and INSERT

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having some trouble trying to do a conditional in `SQL SERVER 2012`.

All I have to do is : when the "TaxId4" (with the 'CPF/CNPJ' alias) is null, then INSERT the data from the field "TaxId0" to the "TaxId4" field (or 'CPF/CNPJ').  Both TaxId4 and TaxId0 are from the same table (CRD7).

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT
    TaxId4 [CPF/CNPJ],
     CASE WHEN TaxId4 = NULL THEN 
        (INSERT INTO CRD7 (TaxId4)
        VALUES (TaxId0) WHERE DocNum = DocNum)
     ELSE 
     END AS ConditDoc
FROM CRD7
```

**EDIT1**

If seomeone could help me on putting that conditional inside another Query, I'd also be glad. Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
    T0.DocNum [Orçamento],
    T0.DocDate [Data Abertura],
    T0.DocDueDate [Data Encerramento],
    T0.CardCode [Cód. Cliente],
    T0.CardName [Nome Cliente],
    T1.Phone1 [Fone Cliente],
    T7.AddrType [Tipo Endereço],
    T1.Address [Endereço Cliente],
    T7.StreetNo [Número Cliente],
    T1.Block [Bairro Cliente],
    T1.ZipCode [CEP Cliente],
    T1.City [Cidade Cliente],
    T8.TaxId0 [CNPJ],
    T8.TaxId4 [CPF],
    T2.TrnspName [Transportadora],
    T3.Quantity [Quantidade Item],
    T3.Price [Preço Unitário Item],
    T3.LineTotal [Total Item],
    T3.ItemCode [Cód. Item],
    T4.ItemName [Nome Item],
    T5.SlpName [Vendedor],
    T6.PymntGroup [Cond. Pagamento],
    T0.PeyMethod [Forma Pagamento]
FROM
    OPOR T0
LEFT JOIN
    OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
LEFT JOIN
    OSHP T2 ON T0.TrnspCode = T2.TrnspCode
LEFT JOIN 
    POR1 T3 ON T0.DocNum = T3.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN
    OITM T4 ON T3.ItemCode = T4.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN
    OSLP T5 ON T3.SlpCode = T5.SlpCode
LEFT JOIN
    OCTG T6 ON T0.GroupNum = T6.GroupNum
LEFT JOIN
    CRD1 T7 ON T1.CardCode = T7.CardCode
LEFT JOIN
    CRD7 T8 ON T1.CardCode = T8.CardCode
```

Comment: Can you please share your table structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: CASE is not for control of flow, its for returning a value ...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the table structure due to its size and complexity.
But, briefly explaining, those two fields are in a 'client table', and TaxId0 = CNPJ and TaxId4 = CPF (both are braziliand documents).
As some people have only one of those documents, all I need is to get TaxId4, and if the person doesn't have that document, than I'll get the TaxId0 one.

Comment: INSERT is for creating a new row, not changing the value in an existing row.   For that you use UPDATE.

Comment: you can not use insert query with select. Also is your question related to crystal report. Its totally unclear that you want. Give your basic input and desire output table structure with 2-3 line of data and explain more.   What do you want with second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN TaxId4 IS NULL THEN "TaxId0"
    ELSE "TaxId4"
    END AS ConditDoc
FROM CRD7
```

It was simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax for `Insert`

```
INSERT INTO CRD7 (TaxId4)
select TaxId0 
FROM CRD7
where TaxId4 is NULL
```

But i think you need this

```
Update CRD7 
set TaxId4  = TaxId0 
where TaxId4 is NULL
```

Comment: Sorry but, it's in portuguese:
Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 2
Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'Update'.
Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 3
Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'ELSE'.


Quick translation: Syntax error near 'upadate', synxtax error near else.
The code:
SELECT
  CASE WHEN TaxId4 = NULL THEN UPDATE CRD7 SET TaxId4 = TaxId0  WHERE TaxId4 is NULL 
  ELSE SET TaxId4 = TaxId4
  END AS ConditDoc
FROM CRD7

Comment: no, You should not add my query inside `select` query just run my query

Comment: Well, then we have a problem. All that is going to a view, so I needed it to be updatable, and not static (as it would be this way).